# Cannot Print Number of Digits Correctly

Tags: java, arrays, formatting

For my current programming project I am supposed to format my testOne & testTwo like "000". While the average is supposed to be "000.0". I have used DecimalFormat to no avail. Furthermore for my letterGradeArray the letter won't display even though the letter grade is in the actual array. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class GradeArray 
{

@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "resource" })
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     //Setup all the variables
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int[] testOne = new int[4]; // Students’ test one grades
     int[] testTwo = new int[4]; // Students’ test two grades
     double[] average = new double[4]; // Students’ average grades
     double z = 002.00;
     char letterGrade = 0;
     char[] letterGradeArray = new char[4];
     DecimalFormat fmt1 = new DecimalFormat("000");
     DecimalFormat fmt2 = new DecimalFormat("000.0");

     //Begin asking for scores
     System.out.println("For test 1,");
     for (int i=0;i<testOne.length;i++)
     {
         System.out.print("Enter score " + (i + 1) + ":");
         testOne[i] = scan.nextInt();
         fmt1.format(testOne[i]);
     }
     System.out.println("\nFor test 2,");
     for (int i=0;i<testTwo.length;i++)
     {
         System.out.print("Enter score " + (i + 1) + ":");
         testTwo[i] = scan.nextInt();
         fmt1.format(testTwo[i]);
     }
     //Compute average                      
     for(int i=0;i<average.length;i++)
     {
            {
               average[i] = (testOne[i]+testTwo[i])/z;
               fmt2.format(average[i]);
            } 
     }
     //Compute letter grade
     for(int i=0;i<average.length;i++)
     {
         if (average[i]>= 90 ) 
            {
             letterGrade = 'A';
            } else if (average[i] >= 80) {
                letterGrade = 'B';
            } else if (average[i] >= 70) {
                letterGrade = 'C';
            } else if (average[i] >= 60) {
                letterGrade = 'D';
            } else {
                letterGrade = 'F';
            }
            //Put the letterGrade into the letterGradeArray
            for(int x=0;i<letterGradeArray[x];x++)
            {
                letterGradeArray[x]=letterGrade;
            } 

     }
     //Print it out      
     System.out.println("Test 1     Test 2     Average     Grade");
     System.out.println("______     ______     _______     _____");
     System.out.println(testOne[0] + "         " + testTwo[0] + "         " + average[0] +"         " + letterGradeArray[0]);
     System.out.println(testOne[1] + "         " + testTwo[1] + "         " + average[1] +"         " + letterGradeArray[1]);
     System.out.println(testOne[2] + "         " + testTwo[2] + "         " + average[2] +"         " + letterGradeArray[2]);
     System.out.println(testOne[3] + "         " + testTwo[3] + "         " + average[3] +"         " + letterGradeArray[3]);
 }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to make this code cleaner do tell me, I feel with all the fors it is clunky.

Comment: slightly wider; there is no specific question?

Comment: No add the leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `fmt1.format(testOne[i]);` but you are not doing anything with the result.  Calling [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(long)) returns a String, it does not affect the thing being passed as a parameter, so when you later print `testOne[0]` etc. you are printing the plain, original, values.

If you want the formatted values you will have to assign the return of `.format()` to something, keep it around, and print it *instead* of the original integer values. For example, patterned after how the rest of your code works...

```
String[] formattedOne = new String[4];
// ... later
formattedOne[i] = fmt1.format(testOne[i]);
// ... still later
System.out.println(formattedOne[0] + "    " ..........
```

Comment: Thank you I figured that out after posting. I still cannot get the letter array to work though.